# Rank function in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have below data in a big query table

```
col1    col2
abc 3/22/2020
abc 3/4/2020
xyz 3/22/2020
xyz 3/4/2020
```

I am trying to get below output.

```
col1    col2
abc 3/22/2020
xyz 3/22/2020
```

For this I have tried using the rank() OVER Partition clause, but no luck. Please advise.

```
select * from (select col1, col2 RANK() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1, col2 desc) as r1 from table1) temp
where temp.r1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close - correct one is (just slight adjustment of your query)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(r1) FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC) AS r1 
  FROM table1) temp 
WHERE r1 = 1
```

WHile above should work, below is more optimal BigQuery'ish option

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY col2 DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, I don't know if this is a good practice but I've done this several times.

```
select col1, MIN(PARSE_DATE('%m-%d-%Y', col2))
group by col1
```